# g++ command including sdl sources doesnt find files

Tags: c++, g++, sdl

I recently had the idea to start coding games in c++, but actually i couldnt even start, because as i was importing sdl, which i want to use, it couldnt find the files and i got this error, anybody knows how to do this?

```
g++ -I src/include -L src/lib -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib\libSDL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2main: No such file or directory
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2main.a when searching for -lSDL2main
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2.a when searching for -lSDL2
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib\libSDL2.a when searching for -lSDL2
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2.a when searching for -lSDL2
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL2: No such file or directory
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2.dll.a when searching for -lSDL2
C:\Users\User\w64devkit\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible src/lib/libSDL2.a when searching for -lSDL2
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

I'd really appreciate every help, thanks in advance

Comment: Did you download the correct library for windows?

Comment: yes, i downloaded it threw github, the mingw one

Comment: They ship two different sets of libraries for mingw, x32 and x64. Try both.